# Mead made with bananas as a nutrient

Tags: wine, mead, brewing, yeast-nutrient

I'm looking at what yeast need to live and nanners seem to have a fair bit of that. I have seen a lot of information on adding them for flavor. If nothing else I will be trying this soon and will update with results.

Comment: Your question is?  If anyone has used bananas as nutrient for yeast?

Comment: Mead usually ferments well enough without bananas, other fruit or indeed without yeast nutrient.

Answer (score 3):

Banana does have a couple of the nutrients yeast needs. Potassium, folic acid, magnesium etc.

Most fruits lack FAN though.

That being said **bananas wouldn't be a complete replacement for a yeast nutrient product.**

Comment: I agree.  Some will add bananas to add body (in wine) but I don't find it has the desired effect. Some banana flavour will remain though.